# How to instantiate nested class

Tags: python, inner-classes

How can I instantiate a variable of type UseInternalClass?

```
MyInstance = ParentClass.UseInternalClass(something=ParentClass.InternalClass({1:2}))
```

If I try the former code, I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'ParentClass' is not defined
```

When I want to instantiate an type of a nested class

```
class ParentClass(object):
    class InternalClass(object):
        def __init__(self, parameter = {}):
            pass
        pass

    class UseInternalClass(object):
        _MyVar

        def __init__(self, something = ParentClass.InternalClass()): #meant to make something type = InternalClass
            _MyVar = something
        pass
```

(All the code is on the same file)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use "ParentClass" inside the definition of the parent class since the interpreter have not yet define the class object named ParentClass. Also, InternalClass will not be define until the class ParentClass is completly define.

Note: I'm note sure what you are trying to do, but if you explain your end goal, we might be able to suggest you something else to realise that.

Comment: I want to define a class type inside a class type, so I can pass complex data as parameter. For example, I have a class "Vehicles", with a function "CreateCar(data)". Then I define a nested class "CarData", to be passed as parameter to the function "CreateCar(data=CarData())"

Comment: You can use dict to do this and passes your argument by keyword, or with the unpacking mecanism (**kwargs). If you really want a class to deal with that. You should declare your helper class outside of the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
class Child:

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y


class Parent:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        y = 2 * x
        self.child = Child(y)
```

As an example, you create an instance of the `Parent` class then access its `Child` as follows:

```
par = Parent(4)

par.child.y  # returns a value of 8
```

Comment: But if the only purpose of Child is to pass data to Parent, I would prefer to write the Child class as nested class inside Parent. If it cannot be done, then there is possible for Parent to expose a constructor of an internal Child?

Comment: I need to define Child inside Parent, to avoid leaving orphaned code everywhere, which is hard to maintain because there is no obvious link between Child and Parent.

Comment: It's not clear to me on what you are actually trying to do. Is there another example you can provide?

Comment: The problem with this is that it does not scale and it pollutes the outer scope. Imaging having two types of parent and two types of children. Then you need names like ParentType1Child and when you rename ParentType1 you also need to rename the matching child to be consistently named. With proper scoping (nested child classes) this would not be a problem at all. Now imaging having deeply nested data structures. Then, you end up with classes like ParentType1ChildType2Node5Part2Section7. This would still not be a problem with nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got it right but i if you're trying to do something like that

```
class Parent:
  class Child:
    def __init__(self,passed_data):
      self.data = passed_data
  class AnotherChild:
    def __init__(self,child=Parent.Child("no data passed"))
      self.child_obj = self.Child(data_to_pass)
```

you can create AnotherChild object as follows

```
another_child = Parent.AnotherChild() 
# here it will use the default value of "no data passed"
```

or you might do it as follows

```
child = Parent.Child("data") # create child object
another_child = Parent.AnotherChild(child) # pass it to new child
```

or pass it directly through your **init**

```
another_child = Parent.AnotherChild(Parent.Child("data"))
```

i guess this should work correctly if you are instantiating in the same file for example parent.py , it worked for me like that
i am not sure if that what you want but i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Look for this ona easy example

class Car:

```
@classmethod
def create_wheel(cls):
    return cls.Wheel()

class Wheel:
    pass
```

o = Car.create_wheel()
print(o) # <**main**.Car.Wheel object at 0x7fde1d8daeb0>

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the outer and inner classes with `__init__()` as shown below:

```py
class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self, arg): # Here
        self.variable = "Outer " + arg
        self.inner = OuterClass.InnerClass(arg)
        
    def outer_method(self, arg):
        print("Outer " + arg)
        
    class InnerClass:
        def __init__(self, arg): # Here
            self.variable = "Inner " + arg
            
        def inner_method(self, arg):
            print("Inner " + arg)

obj = OuterClass("variable") # Here
print(obj.variable)
print(obj.inner.variable)
obj.outer_method("method")
obj.inner.inner_method("method")
```

Output:

```
Outer variable
Inner variable
Outer method
Inner method
```